# Casting Array[Any] to Varargs in Scala

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

I have a method `foo` that takes `Seq[Any]`. For example:

```
def foo(a:Seq[Any]) = println(a.size)

foo(Seq("hi", 1, true)) // prints 3
```

I would have liked to avoid writing `Seq` every time. So I would like to define a method `bar` that I could call as:

```
bar("hi", 1, true)
```

having the same effect as calling `foo(Seq("hi", 1, true))`.

Defining the following:

```
def bar(b:Any *) = foo(b)
```

and using it as:

```
bar("hi", 1, true) // prints 1
```

does not work as expected. It assigns `b` to the first element of the `Seq` passed to `foo`. Is there any way I can define `bar` so that it correctly invokes `foo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Defining `bar` as

```
def bar(b:Any *) = foo(b.toSeq)
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be having that problem, That code should work fine and is working fine for me.

```
scala> def foo(a:Seq[Any]) = println(a.size)
foo: (a: Seq[Any])Unit

scala> def bar( b: Any* ) = foo( b )
bar: (b: Any*)Unit

scala> bar( "hi" , 34, 23 )
3

scala> bar( "hi" , 34, true )
3
```

The reason this is happening is becasue `*-paramters` are implicitly received as `Seq` in function-body. Which means even if you pass multiple `varargs` paramters, these will be received as a Sequence inside your function.

You can again convert a Sequence of things to multiple varargs paramters using the `_*` annotation.

`_*` is the special `annotation` that is usable only in `arguments` to `*-parameter` of a function. It makes any `sequence` to be passed as a `*-parameter`.

Following examples will clear things.

```
scala> val l = List( 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 6, 3 )
l: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 6, 3)    

scala> def pp( ints: Int* ) = println( ints )
pp: (ints: Int*)Unit

// All Int* are implicitly received as a Seq[ Int ]
// Hence, ints will be a Seq[ Int ] in function body
// ( WrappedArray[ int ] in this case ) in function body.
scala> pp( 4, 5, 6 )
WrappedArray( 4, 5, 6 )

// Received as List[ Int ] in this case
scala> pp( l: _* )
List(4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 6, 3)

scala> def a( ints: Int* ) = ints.sum
a: (ints: Int*)Int

// passing a list wont work
scala> a( l )
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
  found   : List[Int]
  required: Int
           a( l )
              ^

// list passed as multiple parameters
scala> a( l: _* )
res8: Int = 34
```

Comment: Strangely, it is working now (Scala 2.11). I had tried this earlier with Scala 2.9 and had the problem.

Comment: Cheers to the strange things... :D.. thats because Scala2.9 was very different from Scala2.11